# Probability Question-Approach?

Tags: probability

Chloe cycles to work with probability $0.6$ and takes the bus with probability $0.4$. She has noticed that she is late $20$% of the time when she takes the bus. Her boss notices that, on average, Chloe is late one time per week (that is per five days). (a) What is the probability that Chloe will be late if she cycles to work?

Comment: What have you tried? Show your work and you thoughts.

Comment: Start by forming an equation for the total probability that Chloe is late. Use the law of Total Expectation.

Comment: P(cycle)=0.6; P(Bus)=0.4; P(Late)=0.2; P(Late/Bus)=0.2. From part a, I understand that I have to find P(Late/ cycle) but not getting how to use the bayes theorem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question well, then the equation will be $0.2×0.4 +x×0.6= 0.2$

$P(L)=P(L\cap B)+P(L\cap C)$

But $P(L\cap B)= P(B)×P(L/B) = 0.4×0.2$

$L$ is Chloe being late

$B$ is her taking the bus

$C$ is her going to work by cycling.

Comment: There is a Part b which states:

Comment: Chloe is late today, and her boss suspects this is because she took the bus. What is
the probability that this guess is correct?

Comment: You'll be looking for $P(B/L)=\frac{P(L\cap B)}{P(L)}$

Comment: if I work it out: 0.4x0.2/0.2 which gives the same answer that Probability of taking a Bus is 0.4. am I reading this right?

Comment: Yes it is true.